# Customizing Layer Display in Map based on Nested Criteria selection with dropdown field outside the Map

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson, maps, jquery

I have about 5 different polygon map layers on a map. Each map layer data is stored as separate JSON file (Eg: continent1.json, continent2.json, ...... continent5.json). Every layer have its own different properties (Eg: Each continent layer contains different country's boundaries and feature details like country name, country type etc). These Continent Layer files are fetched dynamically and gets displayed on the map based on the continent name which i select from a dropdown input field placed outside the map (Eg: If i select continent1 from the dropdown field, then it will display continent1.json layer and it have popup feature display, highlight onmouseover, click zoom events for each country when hovering over the countries of that continent layer.) Upto this, my code is working perfectly.

Now I have another input text field outside the map in which i can enter a country name and when i click a search button, it has to highlight and zoom to that country among the countries of that selected continent. Is there any simple method to achieve this requirement?

My code is as shown below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA==" crossorigin=""></script>
</head>
<body>
  <select id="continent" name="continent" onChange="change_countrytype();">
    <option value="asia">Asia</option>
    <option value="africa">Africa</option>
    <option value="europe">Europe</option>
  </select>
  <select id="countrytype" name="countrytype" style="width:100%">
  </select>
<script>
function change_countrytype()
    {
       var continent = $("#continent").val();
       $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "includes/countrytype.php", //countrytype.php lists data fetched from DB.
        data: "continent="+continent,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response)
            {
                $("#countrytype").html(response);
            }
            });
            var layerName1=continent;   
            if(continent!='')
            {   
                loadContinent(layerName1);
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Please select Continent");  
            }
    }
</script> 
  <input type="text" name="countryname" id="countryname">
  <input type="button" id="searchcountry" value="Search" />
  <div id="map" style="height:600px; width:100%;"></div>

<script>
//BASE LAYER DISPLAY
        const mbAttr = '';  
        mbUrl = 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
    const streets        = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {id: 'mapbox/streets-v11', tileSize: 512, zoomOffset: -1, attribution: mbAttr}),
        sattelite        = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {id: 'mapbox/satellite-v9', tileSize: 512, zoomOffset: -1, attribution: mbAttr})
    ;
    const map = L.map("map", {
        center: [8.4819, 77.0361],
        zoom: 8, 
        layers: [streets]
        });                 
    var baseLayers = {
        "Streets": streets, 
        "Sattelite": sattelite,         
    };
    L.control.layers(baseLayers).addTo(map);
    function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        var popupContent;
        if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
            popupContent = feature.properties.popupContent;
        }
        layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
    }  

//LAYER STYLE
var ConOptions = {
        fillColor: '#FFFF00',
        weight: 1,
        opacity: 1,
        color: '#FFFF00',
        dashArray: 3,
        fillOpacity: 0.2}; 

//HIGHLIGHT LAYER DIVISION
    function highlightFeature(e) {      
        var layer = e.target;
        layer.setStyle({
            weight: 4,
            color: '#000',
            fillOpacity: 0.4
        });
        info.update(layer.feature.properties);
    }

//ZOOM TO LAYER DIVISION    
    function zoomToFeature(e) { map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds()); }     
//LAYER FILE FETCH        
      async function getGeojson1(layerName1) 
      {
        const response1 = await fetch(`${layerName1}.json`);
        const geojson1 = await response1.json();
        return geojson1;
      }  

//LAYERS DISPLAY      
      const layerCaching1 = {};
      const currentDisplayedLayer1 = {};      
      const clearMap1 = () => {
        Object.keys(currentDisplayedLayer1).forEach((layer1) => {
          map.removeLayer(currentDisplayedLayer1[layer1]);
          delete currentDisplayedLayer1[layer1];
        });
      };
      const loadContinent = async (layerName1) => 
      {
      if (layerName1 === "") { return clearMap1(); }
      let geojson1;
      if (!layerCaching1[layerName1]) 
      {  
      const geojsonData1 = await getGeojson1(layerName1);           
      geojson1 = L.geoJSON([geojsonData1], {style: function (feature) { return conOptions; }, 
      onEachFeature : function (feature, layer) 
      {  
      popupOptions = {maxWidth: 450};
      layer.on({ mouseover: highlightFeature, mouseout: resetHighlight, click: zoomToFeature });
      layer.bindPopup("<b>Continent Name: </b>" + feature.properties.CONTINENT +
                    "<br><b>Country Name: </b>" + feature.properties.COUNTRY +
                    "<br><b>Country Type: </b>" + feature.properties.TYPE
                    ,popupOptions);
      }
      });   

      $('#searchcountry').click(function() 
      {    
        var countrytype = $('#countrytype').val();  
        var countryname = $('#countryname').val();
        if(countrytype!='')
          {
            if(countryname!='')
            {
                alert(countryname); // Here instead of alerting country name, i want to highlight and zoom to the particular country name.
            }
            else
            {
                alert ('Please enter Country Name');    
            }
          }
        else
          {
            alert ('Please select Country Type');   
          }
      }); 
    
      } 
      else 
      geojson1 = layerCaching1[layerName1];
      if (Object.keys(currentDisplayedLayer1).length > 0) 
      clearMap1();
      currentDisplayedLayer1[layerName1] = geojson1;
      if (!layerCaching1[layerName1]) 
      layerCaching1[layerName1] = geojson1;
      currentDisplayedLayer1[layerName1].addTo(map); 
    };    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[See my Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/customizing-layer-display-in-map-based-on-nested-criteria-selection-with-dropdown-field-outside-the-map-fknmy?file=/index.html)

I got a simple reference at http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/Search/SearchState.html. but in it, it is using autocomplete method which i dont want to use.

Comment: GISE SE site has policy of focused question, which means on question per question. You have two questions in your question. Please edit your question and limit it to only one question.

Comment: Its not two separate questions. both my queries have connections each other. i have answer for any one of the question independently. but the combined solution is my requirement.

Comment: Then I don't quite understand where is the problem. In the working example you are citing, just replace autocomplete input with click button input.

Comment: Its a simple example i gone through to achieve the requirement. But it is not upto my requirement. My requirement is to display layers and zoom to layer based on multiple feature search criteria.

Comment: Consider the case of Continent Asia. When i select Asia from continent dropdown field, it has to dynamically fetch and display asia.json layer file in map (Upto this, it is working for me as per above code). Now if i select India from another dropdown field it has to remove all other countries boundaries (countries have state boundaries inside too) in that asia layer and display india's boundary along with its state boundaries only. Again if i input 'New Delhi' inside a textbox and click search button, then it has to zoom and highlight to New Delhi, a state of India. Its my requirement.

Comment: This logic is a bit too complex to dive into it without having a working example (like JSFiddle) to play with.

Comment: I had updated the question with my working demo. In my actual scenario those country types are fetched from DB based on the Continent i select. I can display a continent layer when i select one from first dropdown. Now if i select a country type from the 2nd dropdown, it has to display countries in that selected continent with that specific country type only. Means It has to remove all other types of countries in that continent. And atlast if i enter a country number in the textbox, it has to zoom & highlight to that particular country in the selected continent & selected type of countries.

Comment: Your question actually contains two questions. GIS SE site policy of focused questions requires only one question per question. Please edit your question and limit it to only one question.

Comment: Ok. I edited and limited to one question.

Comment: As far as I can understand your question, your simple reference example does just that.